# Why were early aviators' trousers flared at the thigh?

Tags: aviation-history

For example, these dapper outfits:

[image]
(Credit [History Bunker](https://thehistorybunker.co.uk/acatalog/Brown_Leather_-_Historical_leather.html))

What purpose does the extra volume down to the knee serve? Why don't modern pilots wear similar jodhpurs?

Comment: Are you sure they're not just the style of the day? More specifically, the military style, and that many pilots may have been serving or ex-military?

Comment: Because you can't touch this.

Comment: @Jamiec Clearly OP is not sure .... I assume that's why they're asking ;)

Comment: Classy looking pants.

Comment: "It's called fashion, look it up"  -  fashion blogger Nicky Ottav,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not too hard to figure out.  Wikipedia says [Jodhpurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodhpurs) originated from India where they were part fashion and part practicality (the loose fit in the upper half for horse riding comfort) and evolved into the uniform of most western cavalry officers by the turn of the century.

And, in WWI, where did most, or at least a lot, of the pilots come from in the early days?  Cavalry.

Comment: Jodpurs are tight-fitting. Those in the question are "plus-fours", I think.

Comment: @pjc50 *Modern* jodhpurs are tight fitting, but unlike the original design *they are made of stretch fabric*.

Comment: The fact that you spend a lot of time sitting with knees bent both on a horse and in a plane may be relevant

Comment: @pjc50: Those are not plus-fours. Plus-fours are [breeches or trousers that extend 4 inches below the knee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_fours).

Comment: Convincing but condescending. Accepted. Never change, StackExchange.